# Signs to look for a new job?

Tags: management, human-resources, termination

I am new to this company and have been here for a month in managerial role, my manager is also relatively new having been with the company for 5 months.

I work really hard.. even when I go home I keep working. I like the job and want to continue with them. But I have a feeling that I am not what my manager wants and I am not as good as what they expected. I have strong experience but the nature of the business is kinda different. My manager has been doing many changes in the organisation and many of the old employees have been sacked recently.

I heard today that he has a meeting with one of the vendors which I should be involved in but wasn't and I feel I have been excluded.

I asked for feedback from him, he said nothing negative but he cant give feedback till the end of 3 months.

Are there clear signs here that tell I should look for a job or I am still OK?

Is there a diplomatic way to know if I am safe or should look for another job without clarifying that I am worried of being sacked?

Comment: 1. You wrote this almost like a poem; is that your intention? Maybe organizing into 2-3 paragraphs would be better. 2. You're basically asking at the end "what should I do" which is not a good type of question here (it's not really widely applicable).

Comment: If you think every time you feel excluded from a meeting is a sign you are going to be dismissed, you are in for an emotional rollercoaster of a career. I would say start looking just in case, but it seems way too early to start applying based on the warning signals you described (if indeed any of them qualify as warning signals with respect to you...which I am not convinced they are).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to look for a job. Even if there is only a 10% chance you might be getting fired. It's still better to look for a job while still being employed.

This doesn't mean that you should necessarily accept the first job that's offered to you. My point is that you should get the process started just in case.

In a couple of weeks, you'll know more about the situation, so you'll be better equipped to know what you should decide. It's also possible that this process will uncover a better position for you at a different company.